# Predicate Logic / changing the result of a statement by asking statment?

Tags: predicate-logic

Let's have a simple statement that P:(x) is false

```
It's good weather today. (it's not)
```

But by evoking the statement, the result can change.
Is there something in any field of Mathematics that describe this case? Or it's completely out of rules?

I'm sure that my question is not exact, i'm open to any correction.

Thanks.

Comment: Consider this variant of Russell's paradox: Does a function that calls every other non-recursive function call itself? In this example, the process of running the program itself is affecting the parameters that the program checks at run-time. Can you see the problem with this?

Comment: Please, note that in logic a "statement" is a declarative sentence, i.e. an *assertion* and not a question.

Comment: @SystematicDisintegration i tihnk i was searching for answer like this, feel free to post it, i will acept it.

Comment: The title of your question is confusing. The truthness of that statement doesn't change because of asking, it changes by the passage of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this [answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/12632/can-a-proposition-change-its-truth-value).

If you take a tensed view of things, there is, quite clearly, no problem (you only need to check the truth value before evocation of the statement). However, this view is not taken in mathematics often; a tenseless view cannot allow for a statement which changes the truth value that it states. You may declare any such statement whose truth value depends on evocation or temporality to arbitrarily be false by convention.